# Seasonal and visual

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm new here, but I guess this is terribly easy.

One clue:

> Some may be happy to have it to send around in this season, though. Feel free!

[image]

Further indication, removing the "enigmatic" nature of puzzle:

> This is intended to illustrate a New Year 2022 greeting card, find the year in the drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the new hint, one thing I notice is that

> The faces of each cube are divided up into pixels, with the length of the large cube side equal to the length of $16$ pixels and the length of the small cube side being the length of $9$ pixels.
>  This means that the surface area of the large cube is $6 \times 16^2 = 1536$ pixels and the surface area of the small cube is $6 \times 9^2 = 486$ pixels which makes the total surface area of both cubes $1536 + 486 = 2022$ pixels.
>  So perhaps with one cube on top of another we have **one on one** or "1/1", with the puzzling referencing New Years Day 2022.

Comment: The elements you haven't analysed are purely aesthetic arbitrary choices, your answer is complete.

Comment: Note: rot13(V qvqa'g bevtvanyyl znxr guvf nf n chmmyr va gur vagragvba bs cbfgvat guvf urer, V whfg gubhtug nsgre cercnevat zl hfhny Arj Lrne zngurzngvpny terrgvat pneq gung vg pbhyq nyfb znxr na npprcgnoyr chmmyr.)